# How to perform Pagination in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, pagination

I'm trying to do pagination on a table records in ASP.NET Core MVC and Entity Framework. I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O57nsLyZubc) and this is my code:

Pager.cs

```
using System;

namespace WebApp.Models
{
    public class Pager
    {
        public int TotalItems { get; private set; }
        public int CurrentPage { get; private set; }
        public int PageSize { get; private set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; private set; }
        public int StartPage { get; private set; }
        public int EndPage { get; private set; }

        public Pager()
        {    
        }

        public Pager(int totalItems, int page, int pageSize = 10)
        {
            int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)totalItems / (decimal)pageSize);
            int currentPage = page;
            int startPage = currentPage - 5;
            int endPage = currentPage + 4;

            if (startPage <= 0)
            {
                endPage = endPage - (startPage - 1);
                startPage = 1;
            }

            if (endPage > totalPages)
            {
                endPage = totalPages;

                if (endPage > 10)
                {
                    startPage = endPage - 9;
                }
            }

            TotalItems = totalItems;
            CurrentPage = currentPage;
            PageSize = pageSize;
            TotalPages = totalPages;
            StartPage = startPage;
            EndPage = endPage;
        }
    }
}
```

ToursController:

```
public IActionResult AllTours(int pg = 1)
{
        List<Tour> tours = _context.Tour.ToList();
        const int pageSize = 9;

        if (pg < 1)
            pg = 1;

        int recsCount = tours.Count();
        var pager = new Pager(recsCount,pg,pageSize);
        int recSkip = (pg - 1)* pageSize;
        var data = tours.Skip(recSkip).Take(pager.PageSize).ToList();
        this.ViewBag.Pager= pager;

        return View(data);
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApp.Models.Tour>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Tours";
    Pager pager=new Pager();
    int pageNo = 0;

    if (ViewBag.Pager != null)
    {
        pager = ViewBag.Pager;
        pageNo = pager.CurrentPage;
    }
}
<div class="row">
            @if(pager.TotalPages > 0)
                {
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        
                            <div class="pagination mt-30">
                                <ul class="pagination mt-30">
                                    @for(var pge = pager.StartPage;pge <= pager.EndPage;pge++)
                                    {
                                        <li class="@(pge == pager.CurrentPage ? "active" : "")">
                                            <a asp-controller="Tour" asp-action="AllTours" asp-route-pg="@pge">@pge</a>
                                        </li>
                                    }   
                                </ul>    
                            </div>    
                    </div>
                }
        </div>
```

But this code is not doing pagination, when I click on the page number, I get this error:

> This localhost page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:5001/Tour/AllTours?pg=2 HTTP ERROR 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the error message, It shows:

```
https://localhost:5001/Tour/AllTours?pg=2
```

But in your question, You provide your controller is `ToursController`, So try to change `asp-controller="Tour"` to `asp-controller="Tours"`.

The point I am very confused about is your action name is `AllTours`, In general, the corresponding page is `AllTours.cshtml`, But you write `Index.cshtml` in your question, So I'm not sure if you wrote the question wrong or if you really wrote the page on `Index.cshtml`.

The default route template `{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}`, So If you write action `AllTours` to page `Index.cshtml`, The url will not correctly navigate to that page.

Comment: Thank you very much i was missing the 's' of 'Tours' as you said. thanks again

Comment: Actually, I don't understand why you unmarked this Answer...